# Permission denied error when trying to download admin file using Box API

Tags: box-api

I get 403 access_denied_insufficient_permissions error when trying to access a file present on box enterprise admin account.

We use the "as-user" header to access files of any user on the enterprise. In our case, bob@acme.com is the admin user and he gave access to my box application the permission to access any files. If I try to access files on bob's account using "As-user" or "On-behalf-of: bob@acme.com" header, I get access denied error. If I do not use this header, I am able to access the documents. I don't think this is a valid work around for this issue as we do not know at run-time if a user is admin or a regular user. Have any of you run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Box recently made a change in their Oauth token scopes. Every app now carries an additional setting to allow the app to have scope level of managing the enterprise. You need to enable that on your app and then see what happens. It should work, I think.

We faced the same issues a few days back and due the above suggested change worked for us. [Here](http://developers.box.com/roadmap/) is the announcement from box.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well. What you can do is to ask the Box API to get the current user and compare that userId to the one you are going to be running as. If they differ, add As-user header, otherwise don't.

It does require one extra API call (getCurrentUser), but it works.

It's a little silly, it seems it would be a very easy thing to fix on the box end.